# Taking and restoring an image of partition with dd

Tags: linux, backup, dd

I created a new partition on my server /dev/sda4 with a filesystem based on ext3.

I mounted the new partition /dev/sda4 on /mnt/sda4/ and created an image with dd of the partition /dev/sda3. sda3 is mounted on the root folder (cd /) so it contains the most important files.

Creation of the image:

```
dd if=/dev/sda3 of=/mnt/sda4/backup.img
```

Then I removed a file on /var/www/html/ which is on the partition sda3. I tried to restore the image and it worked, but the file which I removed earlier isn't in back in place.

restoring:

```
dd if=/mnt/sda4/backup.img of=/dev/sda3
```

Output:

```
[root@h9999 sda4]# dd if=backup.img of=/dev/sda3
982128+0 records in
982128+0 records out
502849536 bytes (503 MB) copied, 1.13645 s, 442 MB/s
```

So actually it should work, shouldn't it?

Comment: What does `mount` say? `/var` might well be in another partition...

Comment: You mean mounting the image file? I checked df -h and the /var folder isnt located elsewhere.

Comment: Wait... Have you restored the backup while /dev/sda3 was still mounted?

Comment: Hey Igeorget, yes I tried it. Since the /dev/sda3 is mounted on the root filesystem I cant unmount it because I then have no other place to save the image.

Comment: @ugo that's pretty dangerous. dd works at byte level. If you modify the partition directly instead of through the filesystem while it's mounted you have a fair chance of corrupting it.

Answer (score 3):

There are several reasons why this may have failed: /var/www/html could actually be a symlink to somewhere else in your filesystem (try `ls -la /var/www/` to see if there is a line like `html -> /foo/bar/html`. If /dev/sda3 was mounted during either of your dd processes, the filesystem may have been corrupted so that you don't see that file any more.

Using dd is in most cases not the best way to make a backup image of a disk, because dd copies everything including empty sectors and can only restore to a disk/partition of exactly the same size. Try [partimage](https://www.partimage.org/Main_Page) instead, which will copy only used sectors.

In most cases, [using tar](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem/TAR) is actually the best option to create a backup of linux filesystems because this gives you independence of the filesystem and partition size used in the original partition and thus make the restoring process much more flexible. If you are worried about loosing the boot loader, [the link I gave above](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem/TAR) also explains how you can restore the boot loader during the restoration process using a live cd, which is just a few additional lines of code apart from creating the partitions.

Comment: what does *can only restore to a disk/partition of exactly the same size* mean? i dont think that's how `dd` works. and the question does specify a partition image - not a filesystem.

Comment: Hey Thawn, so to sum up. The partition does not have to be mounted or otherwise it can produce a corrupted image. But since /dev/sda3 is mounted on the root filesystem which also includes my /mnt/ folder, Its not really possible to unmount it. Here is what it says: umount: /: device is busy. Actually I want to create a full filesystem backup in order to recreate my server in a matter of minutes. How does Amazon Web Services does this? You can create there AMIs (Amazon Machine Images) in a few minutes...

Comment: Update: tried it with partimage, same error, the partition has to be unmounted.

Comment: That's why I recommended tar. That works on a mounted partition.

Comment: If you want to back up you root partition with dd or partimage, you have to boot from a [live cd such as systemRescueCD](https://www.system-rescue-cd.org/SystemRescueCd_Homepage).

Comment: Amazon uses a completely different approach: They run virtual machines and take snapshots of the disk images which can be quickly restored. I am quite sure you don't want the administrative and performance overhead associated with that.

Comment: @mikeserv have you ever tried to dd to a partition of different size? In the best case (the new partition is larger than the image). you end up with a filesystem that is too small for your partition and waste some space. In the worst case (new partition is smaller and there is another partition behind it) you end up corrupting not only the current but also other partitions on the disk. dd is powerful but also dangerous!

Comment: @Thawn, okay now I got the point. Is tar really that good? I mean what about locked files, is backing up the root partition files then even possible? Its like copying mysql's frm files for a backup, I heard this can produce corrupt backup files and also interfere read and write queries because of the file locking. Thats why LVM/mysqldump etc. is used most of the time, as far as I know...

Comment: you are correct that running processes can in certain cases lead to inconsistent data in your backup. Therefore it is recommended to stop as many daemons (including mysql) as possible for the duration of the backup. The safest way is still to boot the system from a live cd and back up from there (you can still use tar, though). In practice however, most filesystem writes in an idling system happen to folders such as /proc and /sys or /tmp which you don't need or want to back up anyways because they are created at boot time. I have not had any problems with backups created with tar so far.

Comment: However do note that as you mentioned mysql is a special case. Mysql will complain if you back up the data directory while the daemon is running. I use mysqldump to back up my mysql databases separately.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for the explanations. I was restoring a 3.6GB sql file a few days ago with standard mysql cli, it was terribly slow. It took about 2 hours, although I deactivated autocommitting. I will try it tomorrow as a test with mydumper, this tool is multi-threaded and works faster they say.